# Spring data neo4j client throws exception when there's no match in database

Tags: spring, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I'm using Neo4jClient to do the query since my source and target node have the same label.

Following is how I do the query

```
@Repository
public class Neo4jClientRepository {
    @Autowired
    private Neo4jMappingContext neo4jMappingContext;

    @Autowired
    private Neo4jClient neo4jClient;

    public Collection<NodePair> findNodesByUniqueIds(List<String> srcUniqueIds, String nodeName) {
        BiFunction<TypeSystem, MapAccessor, Node> mappingFunction = neo4jMappingContext.getRequiredMappingFunctionFor(Node.class);

        return neo4jClient.query(
                        """
                                MATCH (src:Node)
                                WHERE src.uniqueId IN $uniqueIds
                                OPTIONAL MATCH (src:Node)-[*1..2]-(target:Node)
                                WHERE toUpper(target.name) = toUpper($name)
                                RETURN {src: src, target: target} AS nodePair
                                """)
                .bind(srcUniqueIds).to("uniqueIds")
                .bind(nodeName).to("name")
                .fetchAs(NodePair.class)
                .mappedBy((typeSystem, record) -> {
                        MapValue nodePair = (MapValue) record.get("nodePair");
                        var src = mappingFunction.apply(typeSystem, nodePair.get("src"));
                        var target = mappingFunction.apply(typeSystem, nodePair.get("target"));
                    return new NodePair(src, target);
                })
                .all();
    }
}
```

The function works fine when there's a match in the database.

However, for some business cases, the above query doesn't necessarily have a match, meaning it will return empty results based on different inputs. When there's no match, the following exception will be thrown

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: NULL is not iterable; Error code 'N/A'
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateImpl(Neo4jPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:107)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(Neo4jPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.DefaultNeo4jClient.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(DefaultNeo4jClient.java:230)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.DefaultNeo4jClient$DefaultRecordFetchSpec.all(DefaultNeo4jClient.java:488)
```

Is there a way to do a null check before the result being mapped to entity class? Or how could I avoid this kind of situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your mapping code to

```
MapValue nodePair = (MapValue) record.get("nodePair");
var src = mappingFunction.apply(typeSystem, nodePair.get("src"));
if (!nodePair.get("target").isNull()) {
    var target = mappingFunction.apply(typeSystem, nodePair.get("target"));
    return new NodePair(src, target);
}
return new NodePair(src, null);
```

and check the `null` value that the driver returns in this case.

(Also answered this at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/issues/2821 but wanted to be sure that the answer can be discovered also here by others having the same problem)

Comment: Thanks! I should have thought of this earlier. Btw, if there's a relationship property between these two nodes, is there a way to retrieve it? I've defined a `@Relationship("some_relationship") private SomeRelationshipProperty property` in the node class, but when I use the above projection (NodePair contains Node src, Node target), this `property` is empty in the result even there's a match

Comment: RelationshipProperties are not an entity like class. For this you would have to parse them manually. Name `[r:*1..2]` and return them `{src: src, r:r, target: target}`. Than you would be able to access them in the the _nodePair_ `MapValue` like you do the nodes `nodePair.get("r").asRelationship()`.

Comment: I see, this makes sense. If I modify the query above to something like `MATCH path = (src:Node)-[*1..2]-(target:Node) WHERE toUpper(target.name) = toUpper($name) AND src.uniqueId IN $uniqueIds RETURN nodes(path) as nodes, rels(path) as rels`, normally I can use `Iterable<Map<String, Object>>` to catch the returned value. But in this case, the start and end node are the same label and the query would throw an exception. Is there a way to retrieve the path information by modifying the neo4jclient code above? I tried to design a PathEntity to do the mapping, but the relationship is dynamic here.